# modify iframe hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Can I modify an iframe's anchor tags with javascript / jquery? I want to modify all anchor tags within the iframe to add a `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Iframe src is not in the same domain as the parent page, you can't because of the **same origin policy**.

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
$("#iFrameName").contents().find("a").attr('target','_blank')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the location of the document referenced in the iFrame is in the same domain as the parent document, you can access the anchor tags with this line of JavaScript:

```
{reference to iframe}.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

That will return an array, and you can then loop through it and change all the target attributes to "_blank".

I don't think you can do this with a 3rd-party URL because of cross-domain security issues.