# About javascript on iframe

Tags: javascript, css, html

When a link is opened in iframe. And if we click on another link on Web page inside iframe. That link is getting opened in new tab outside the iframe. 
So how can I open both the links in iframe,
Does it possible through JavaScript.

Comment: Is the framed page under your control, or is it third-party?  if it's not your site you won't be able to modify its behavior.

Comment: Yeah framed page is third party page.

Comment: In that case: Possible duplicate of [modify iframe hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083092/modify-iframe-hyperlinks)

Answer (score -1):

you can use the "target" attribute.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_name.asp)